# How to rename a file, using exiftool, to a new name contained in CSV import file

Tags: csv, rename, exiftool

Using exiftool, I have exported image file data to a CSV file.  I have manipulated that data and now I want to import the new values to the original files.  Everything works as I would expect, except that I want also to rename images to new file names contained in the CSV file (those new names were generated manually as well as by programs; they could not be generated by a rule).  I know how to rename files using data that is in the source image file (e.g. I've found advice on how to incorporate the camera model name into the file name), but I don't know how to rename the source image file to the name that I have specified in the CSV file.

It would be simple enough to do this renaming separately from exiftool, but I'm curious to know whether exiftool can do it.  It seems to be able to do pretty much anything else.

Comment: -o might be the option you're looking for.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: I haven't tried it, only read the documentation, but "-o" doesn't seem to have anything to do with taking the new file name from the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=9190.0), Phil Harvey (creator of exiftool) says it isn't possible to rename files from a CSV file.  It's "a feature to prevent people from messing up their files unintentionally."

Comment: Thanks for that link ...  tho' I really wanted that ability to mess up my files intentionally.

Comment: You could change the column header which holds the filename you want to rename to a tag you don't use, and then use exiftool to rename based upon that tag.

Comment: I thought of that -- that would take two passes with exiftool -- but that seems to me to be a kludge, stretching to use exiftool when it's cleaner and simpler to instead use the relevant CSV columns to generate a batch file of RENAME commands.